# Write the script to check remote host services running or not

Tags: bash, shell

This is the script but output is wrong even Apache is running its show stop. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

```
ssh -qn root@ ip

if ps aux | grep [h]ttpd > /dev/null
then
    echo "Apcache is running"
else
    echo "Apcahe is not running"

fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
if ssh -qn root@ip pidof httpd &>/dev/null ; then
     echo "Apache is running";
     exit 0;
else
     echo "Apache is not running";
     exit 1;
fi
```

These `exit` commands will send the correct **EXIT_SUCCESS** and **EXIT_FAILURE** too ( Will be usefull to extend this script in future, if you need ).

> > **But ONE ADVICE : Is better to put the script as a remote process to run with a sudoer user over ssh account**

Answer (score 1):

You are not running the commands on the remote host.

Try this instead.

```
if ssh -qn root@ip ps aux | grep -q httpd; then
    echo "Apache is running"
else
    echo "Apache is not running"
fi
```

Just to be explicit, `ps aux` is the argument to `ssh` and so that is what is being executed on the remote host.  The `grep` runs as a child of the local script.

Comment: Agree. Besides, to check whether a service is running, I would rather use something like `/etc/init.d/httpd status | grep pid` instead of `ps aux|grep -q httpd`

Answer (score 0):

First of all httpd is not available in ubuntu. For ubuntu apache2 is available.

So this command `ps aux | grep [h]ttpd` will not work on ubuntu.

No need to write any script to check the apache status. From ubuntu terminal run this command to get the status:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Output will be:

A > if apache is running: `Apache2 is running (pid 1234)`

B > if apache is not running: `Apache2 is NOT running.`

Answer (score 0):

Since **ssh returns with exit status of the remote command** check man page for ssh and search for exit status

so Its as simple as

```
ssh root@ip "/etc/init.d/apache2 status"
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then                       # if service is running exit status is 0 for "/etc/init.d/apache2 status"
 echo "Apache is not running"
else 
 echo "Apache is running"
fi
```

You do not need ps or grep for this

Comment: Explicitly examining `$?` is an antipattern.  The purpose of `if` and friends is precisely to run a command and check its exit status.  The idiomatic way to write this is thus `if ssh root@ip "/etc/init.d/apache2 status"; then ...` (where the quoting in this case is actually optional).